# Change camera recording codec programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, codec

I'm using the following code to record the camera in Android. How can I change the default codec (the default is H264) here?

```
private Uri fileUri;
//...
        private void recordVideo() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            // set video quality
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
    
            // start the video capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    
    // ...
    
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // play the video given the global fileUri 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent. You have to open the camera in your app and handle recording video by yourself. The [official example](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXVideo) using CameraX library are a good starting point.

To control the codec, you need an extra step. You can borrow from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63528509/192373), which enforces h264 – but you are free to choose `MediaCodec.createEncoderByType()` the way you like.

Comment: Isn't there "any" ways to do it? (non-safe way is fine). I noticed something like `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MediaColumns.BITRATE,"30.00");` to set bitrates. Not sure if it works though.

Comment: + I added my code. Can you please specify the exact changes in my code? I also saw we can use `mediaRecorder` to achieve this.

Comment: As I say, the change is substantial, because the Intent action cannot be used. There are quite [a few examples also on the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-record-a-video-in-my-android-app). I am not aware of any device that has non-standard *extras* for camera that control the choice of video codec.